# Angular JS Controller with Filter For JSON Array Of Objects

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-controller, angularjs-filter, ng-filter

I have below kind of JSON and I wanted to find the number of objects with `Status : 1` in JSON and I have tried with below approach and its not working .

And I know ng-filter needs to applied only to Array but I am not finding a way to do it in the below JSON data, Can someone help me

I am getting error as expected but how to resolve this issue in my case

`[filter:notarray] Expected array but received:`

[**Plunker Demo**](https://plnkr.co/edit/tXL3X4ESFOlvrihTT4KR?p=preview)

In the Below JSON Data As you see I have Array with Arrays and I should get the 
Count of **Status with value 1**

**Expected Output**

Count Of 1st Array  : 1
Count of 2nd Array  : 3
Count of 3rd Array  : 1

**JSON Data**

```
    [
  [{
    "id": 252323,
    "orderId": 223505,
    "status": 1,
    "executedOn": "13/Sep/17",
    "executedBy": "Person A",
    "executedByDisplay": "Person A",
    "cycleId": 3994,
    "cycleName": "Cycle A",
    "versionId": 21291,
    "versionName": "Version A",
    "issueKey": "Key-12561"
  }],
  [{
    "id": 253077,
    "orderId": 224047,
    "status": 1,
    "executedOn": "26/Sep/17",
    "executedBy": "Person B",
    "executedByDisplay": "Person B",
    "cycleId": 4012,
    "cycleName": "Cycle B",
    "versionId": 22912,
    "versionName": "Version B",
    "issueKey": "Key-12580"
  }, {
    "id": 253076,
    "orderId": 224046,
    "status": 2,
    "executedOn": "20/Sep/17",
    "executedBy": "Person B",
    "executedByDisplay": "Person B",
    "cycleId": 4012,
    "cycleName": "Cycle B",
    "versionId": 22912,
    "versionName": "Version B",
    "issueKey": "Key-12578"
  }, {
    "id": 253075,
    "orderId": 224045,
    "status": 1,
    "executedOn": "20/Sep/17",
    "executedBy": "Person B",
    "executedByDisplay": "Person B",
    "cycleId": 4012,
    "cycleName": "Cycle B",
    "versionId": 22912,
    "versionName": "Version B",
    "issueKey": "Key-12582"
  }, {
    "id": 253074,
    "orderId": 224044,
    "status": 1,
    "executedOn": "20/Sep/17",
    "executedBy": "Person B",
    "executedByDisplay": "Person B",
    "cycleId": 4012,
    "cycleName": "Cycle B",
    "versionId": 22912,
    "versionName": "Version B",
    "issueKey": "Key-12584"
  }],
  [{
    "id": 255168,
    "orderId": 226138,
    "status": 1,
    "executedOn": "26/Sep/17",
    "executedBy": "Person A",
    "executedByDisplay": "Person A",
    "cycleId": 4022,
    "cycleName": "Cycle C",
    "versionId": 21291,
    "versionName": "Version A",
    "issueKey": "Key-12617"
  }]
]
```

Angular JS Code

```
var app = angular.module('studentApp', []);

app.controller('StudentCntrl', function($scope, $http, $filter) {
  $http.get('data.json').then(function(response) {

    $scope.value = response.data;

    $scope.value.forEach(function(items) {
      $scope.eachValue = items;
      items.forEach(function(insideItems) {
        passvalue = $filter('filter')(insideItems, function(inputs) {
          if (inputs.status == '1')
            console.log(inputs.length);
          return inputs;
        });
      });

    });
  });
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can simply use [java script array filter](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter)  something like

```
 arr.filter( function(a){return a.status==1}).length
```

Or using angular

```
 $filter('filter')(v, function(vc) {return vc.status ==1}).length
```

[Here is working demo](https://plnkr.co/edit/l7VTFOwnKpWOkdNZuFx7?p=preview)

Comment: Thanks This what I wanted!! Is there any way I can implement with angular js filter the same thing